# Why does this only produce a white square with no buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Why does this only produce a white square with no buttons?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.PRINT = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Print', fg = 'Red', command = self.Print)
        self.PRINT.pack(side = 'left')


        self.QUIT = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Quit', fg = 'Red', command = self.quit())
        self.QUIT.pack(side = 'left')


    def Print(self):
        print('at least somethings working')


root = tk.Tk()
b = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

even though I called the buttons and packed them?

Comment: Watch out! You have two Frame(s): the Application (which is-a Frame) and a “frame” in the local context of the __init__. Try to remove the latter and add the buttons to “self” (which is a reference to the Application/Frame)

Comment: Your frame is not packed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few issues.

Lets start with the frame variable.

From what I can see its really not needed. You have created a class that inherits  from frame. You can leave it as is but you will need to use a grid manager to place it either in the class frame or in the root window.

I think you should remove it and just use self on the buttons.

Next because we are using the class frame lets use a grid manager to place that frame on the root window.

For this we can just use `pack()`.

This should clear it up for you.

See below code.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.PRINT = tk.Button(self, text = 'Print', fg = 'Red', command = self.Print)
        self.PRINT.pack(side = 'left')


        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text = 'Quit', fg = 'Red', command = self.quit)
        self.QUIT.pack(side = 'left')


    def Print(self):
        print('at least somethings working')


root = tk.Tk()
b = Application(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Also, `command = self.quit()` should be `command = self.quit`.

Comment: Yes I did see that but forgot to correct it in the code. Thanks for pointing that out.